# How can i convert Ether from the PoW chain in to Ether on the PoS chain?

Tags: ether, uniswap, proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, pow

I am basically looking to convert the ETHW (proof of work Ether) to PoS ETH ( proof of stake ether )

and i understand that [ETHW has no contract address](https://medium.com/@ETHW/faqs-fd2fba846eca), since it is NOT an ERC-20 token

instead it is a native currency on the 'old' ethereum Proof of Work (PoW) network

so it will not be exchanged like a usual token swap ( i.e protocols like UniSwap are useless in this scenario)

therefore, any ideas on how i can exchange this native currency of ETHW in to ETH PoS ?

Comment: There is no ETHW or PoS ETH. There is only one and only 1 ETH.

Comment: @AdamBoudj please refer to : https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum-pow/ AND/OR : https://ethereumpow.org/

Answer (score 0):

There's no cross-chain liquidity or decentralized bridges that I know between POW and POS ethereum. So the only option you have is to sell ETHW on a Cex and buy ETH there.

Comment: what would be the most reliable Centralized Exchange ( Cex ? ) to do this ?

Comment: Check on the Markets page https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum-pow/markets/. I see Kucoin, Kraken, Bitfinex are all ok IMHO.